# Accentuation in python: structure and for loop

Tags: python, encoding, non-ascii-characters

I've got a set filled with value that are present in a JSON, when I print my set I got the following output:

```
set(['Path\xc3\xa9', 'Synergy Cin\xc3\xa9ma'])
```

but if I print each element by using a for loop I've got the following output:

```
Pathé
Synergy Cinéma
```

Why I don't got the same encoding for each words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are using python 2 and it might be related to the default encoding behavior. The value stocked in your set is the "encoded" value and when you use `print` (which is based on the underlying `__repr__` and/or `__str__` methods of the object) you get the decoded/formated output (according to the default system encoding).

You can obtain information about the default encoding used with the function `sys.getdefaultencoding()`

Note that in python 3, encoding is `utf-8` by default (ie. by default "any string created (...) is stored as Unicode", according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)) and you wont have the exact same behavior (you can see in the *python 2* snippet that the hashed values, as python `set`s are based on them, are the same if your input string is encoded or not) :

**Python 2 :**

```
>>> a = b'Path\xc3\xa9'
>>> a
'Path\xc3\xa9'
>>> print(a)
Pathé
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
>>> hash('Pathé')
8776754739882320435
>>> hash(b'Path\xc3\xa9')
8776754739882320435
```

**Python 3:**

```
>>> a = b'Path\xc3\xa9'
>>> a
b'Path\xc3\xa9'
>>> print(a)
b'Path\xc3\xa9'
>>> print(a.decode())
Pathé
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
>>> hash("Pathé")
1530394699459763000
>>> hash(b"Path\xc3\xa9")
1621747577200686773
```